# Still FK conflict, even after investigation

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

4.857 million rows went through the flow OK, and only 38.000 rows sent to error output. This due to a FK conflict. ---> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_FactTransactions_DimCustomer". 
The conflict occurred in database "", table "dbo.DimCustomer", column 'CustomerNr'.".

My problem is, after some investigation, i can't identify any conflict in the primary table dbo.dimcustomer.

Lets take Mid(Named CustomerNr in the DB) "60534658" for an example and let us see.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Picture NR 
1: This is a data-view draft of some of the rows that got sent to error output for analysis.

2: This is the table where its supposed to insert, notice that rows with the same CustomerNr already exists, because some rows of the same CustomerNr, for a strange reason, got inserted while others did not

3: And last. This is the actual primary table(Customer table), where the Mid(CustomerNr) reference clearly exists!

Am i missing something here? why is it still in conflict?
ty for any answers!

---

TABLE STRUCTURE:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimCustomer](
    [CustomerNr] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NULL,
    [GeographyKey] [int] NULL,
    [OrgNum] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CustomerName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Adress] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ZipCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [MCC_Code] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Dim.Customer_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomerNr] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DimCustomer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DimCustomer_DimGeography] FOREIGN KEY([GeographyKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimGeography] ([GeographyKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DimCustomer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DimCustomer_DimGeography]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactTransactions](
    [TransactionKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Reportdate] [date] NULL,
    [CustomerNr] [int] NULL,
    [SchemeID] [smallint] NULL,
    [PriceType] [int] NULL,
    [Count] [int] NULL,
    [Amount] [float] NULL,
    [Commission] [float] NULL,
    [InterchangeFee] [float] NULL,
    [Currency] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [FeeType] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FactTransactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[TransactionKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactTransactions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactTransactions_DimCardScheme] FOREIGN KEY([SchemeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimCardScheme] ([SchemeID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactTransactions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactTransactions_DimCardScheme]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactTransactions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactTransactions_DimCustomer] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerNr])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimCustomer] ([CustomerNr])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactTransactions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactTransactions_DimCustomer]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactTransactions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactTransactions_DimDate] FOREIGN KEY([Reportdate])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimDate] ([Date])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactTransactions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactTransactions_DimDate]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactTransactions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactTransactions_DimPriceType] FOREIGN KEY([PriceType])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DimPriceType] ([PriceType])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactTransactions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactTransactions_DimPriceType]
GO
```

---

Example error output line:

2015-05-01,60534658,1,1,57,484,5280,3000000000002,78,340000000000003,0,EUR,57,1

Comment: Please post definition of `FK_FactTransactions_DimCustomer`

Comment: CONSTRAINT FK_FactTransactions_DimCustomer FOREIGN KEY (CustomerNr)
REFERENCES DimCustomer(CustomerNr)

Comment: To analyse the issue further can you plz post the table structures and a sample insert line which is not working.

Comment: Added table structures for the relevant tables and a sample insert line.

Comment: Can you provide it as text? Not as an image?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some FactTrancsactions pointing to a customer which doesn't exist.

Try this statement to check if there are some transaction pointing to the wrong customer. Each row returned by this statement will bounce if you create the foreign key.

```
SELECT ft.*
FROM dbo.FactTransactions as ft
LEFT JOIN dbo.DimCustomer as dc
        ON ft.CustomerNr = dc.CustomerNr
WHERE dc.CustomerNr IS NULL
```

Comment: This query returned zero

Comment: But the rows that conflict exists in the primary table as a existing customer.

Comment: Mh, well I checked it on my side too. I can't get an error. I tried it to. I removed all additional check constraints which I can't handle. Just the one left which causes your error. And it works for me. Just one idea left. May it be, that your application first tries to insert Transaction and after that tries to add the rows to `FactTransactions`?

Comment: It's a SSIS-package. And the dataflow i execute will populate data to the FactTransaction-table. The DB structure already exists, its just a package that populates. The data in DimCustomer also pre-exists.

Comment: thanks for your concern but this is a tricky one! I will test the source information(Access DB) if these rows differs. Maybe it could be a comma-seperated issue that change column position or something. I will try to do ETL on the "error output flatfile" and insert those values. If i manage to fix it ill let you know!

Comment: Yes thanks. Would be nice to see the answer also. :-)